# Условия срабатывания валидатора

Tags: javascript, jquery

Необходимо, чтобы кнопка submit разблокировалась только при всех выполненных условиях, как это реализовать?

Ссылка на сайт: http://test.truskahouses.in.ua/pura/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var patternmail = /^[a-z0-9_-]+@[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}$/i;
  var mail = $('#mail');
  var name = $('#firstname');
  var lname = $('#lastname');
  var phone = $('#phone');
  var text = $('#text');
  $('.alert-danger').hide(1);


  mail.blur(function(){
    if(mail.val() != ''){
        if(mail.val().search(patternmail) == 0){
          $('#alertmail').hide(1)
          $('#submit').attr('disabled', false);
          mail.removeClass('error').addClass('ok');
          $('#mail').css('border', 0);
        }else{
          $('#alertmail').show(1)
          $('#mail').css('border', '2px solid #cc3b3b');
          $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
          mail.addClass('ok');
        }
      }else{
        mail.addClass('error');
        $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
      }
  });

  name.blur(function(){
    if(name.val() != ''){
        if(name.val().length >= 3){
          $('#alertname').hide(1)
          $('#submit').attr('disabled', false);
          name.removeClass('error').addClass('ok');
          $('#firstname').css('border', 0);
        }else{
          $('#alertname').show(1)
          $('#firstname').css('border', '2px solid #cc3b3b');
          $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
          name.addClass('ok');
        }
      }else{
        name.addClass('error');
        $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
      }
  });

  lname.blur(function(){
    if(lname.val() != ''){
        if(lname.val().length >= 3){
          $('#alertlname').hide(1)
          $('#submit').attr('disabled', false);
          lname.removeClass('error').addClass('ok');
          $('#lastname').css('border', 0);
        }else{
          $('#alertlname').show(1)
          $('#lastname').css('border', '2px solid #cc3b3b');
          $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
          lname.addClass('ok');
        }
      }else{
        lname.addClass('error');
        $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
      }
  });

    phone.blur(function(){
        if(phone.val() != ''){
            if(phone.val().length >= 9 ){
                $('#alertphone').hide(1)
                $('#submit').attr('disabled', false);
                phone.removeClass('error').addClass('ok');
                $('#phone').css('border', 0);
            }else{
                $('#alertphone').show(1)
                $('#phone').css('border', '2px solid #cc3b3b');
                $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
                phone.addClass('ok');
            }
        }else{
            phone.addClass('error');
            $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
        }
    });

    text.blur(function(){
        if(text.val() != ''){
            if(text.val().length >= 10){
                $('#alerttext').hide(1)
                $('#submit').attr('disabled', false);
                text.removeClass('error').addClass('ok');
                $('#text').css('border', 0);
            }else{
                $('#alerttext').show(1)
                $('#text').css('border', '2px solid #cc3b3b');
                $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
                text.addClass('ok');
            }
        }else{
            text.addClass('error');
            $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вешаем проверку по всем input по нажатию на клавишу на все поля
2. Добавляем переменную со значением true
3. Если где-то не проходит проверку, меняем значение переменной на false
4. В конце проверяем переменную: если она равна true, то разблокируем кнопка, если false - то блокируем

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var patternmail = /^[a-z0-9_-]+@[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}$/i;
  var mail = $('#mail');
  var name = $('#firstname');
  var lname = $('#lastname');
  var phone = $('#phone');
  var text = $('#text');

  var allInputs = $('#mail, #firstname, #lastname, #phone, #text');

  $('.alert-danger').hide(1);

  allInputs.on('input', function() {
    var resolution = true;
  
    if (mail.val() != '') {
      if (mail.val().search(patternmail) == 0) {
        $('#alertmail').hide(1)
        $('#submit').attr('disabled', false);
        mail.removeClass('error').addClass('ok');
        $('#mail').css('border', 0);
      } else {
        $('#alertmail').show(1)
        $('#mail').css('border', '2px solid #cc3b3b');
        mail.addClass('ok');

        resolution = false;
      }
    } else {
      mail.addClass('error');

      resolution = false;
    }

    if (name.val() != '') {
      if (name.val().length >= 3) {
        $('#alertname').hide(1)
        name.removeClass('error').addClass('ok');
        $('#firstname').css('border', 0);
      } else {
        $('#alertname').show(1)
        $('#firstname').css('border', '2px solid #cc3b3b');

        resolution = false;

        name.addClass('ok');
      }
    } else {
      name.addClass('error');

      resolution = false;
    }

    if (lname.val() != '') {
      if (lname.val().length >= 3) {
        $('#alertlname').hide(1)
        lname.removeClass('error').addClass('ok');
        $('#lastname').css('border', 0);
      } else {
        $('#alertlname').show(1)
        $('#lastname').css('border', '2px solid #cc3b3b');

        resolution = false;

        lname.addClass('ok');
      }
    } else {
      lname.addClass('error');

      resolution = false;
    }

    if (phone.val() != '') {
      if (phone.val().length >= 9) {
        $('#alertphone').hide(1)
        phone.removeClass('error').addClass('ok');
        $('#phone').css('border', 0);
      } else {
        $('#alertphone').show(1)
        $('#phone').css('border', '2px solid #cc3b3b');

        resolution = false;

        phone.addClass('ok');
      }
    } else {
      phone.addClass('error');

      resolution = false;
    }

    if (text.val() != '') {
      if (text.val().length >= 10) {
        $('#alerttext').hide(1)
        text.removeClass('error').addClass('ok');
        $('#text').css('border', 0);
      } else {
        $('#alerttext').show(1)
        $('#text').css('border', '2px solid #cc3b3b');

        resolution = false;

        text.addClass('ok');
      }
    } else {
      text.addClass('error');

      resolution = false;
    };
    
    if(resolution === true){
      $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
    }else{
      $('#submit').attr('disabled', '');
    };
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="alertmail" class="alert-danger"></div>

<p>mail: <input type="text" id="mail"></p>
<p>firstname: <input type="text" id="firstname"></p>
<p>lastname: <input type="text" id="lastname"></p>
<p>phone: <input type="text" id="phone"></p>
<p>text: <input type="text" id="text"></p>

<p><input type="submit" id="submit" disabled></p>
```

Comment: Юрий, у нас проблемы))
Залили, теперь он просто не даёт отправить в любом случае :)

Comment: @user234223, тут-то работает :) Я проверил

Comment: @user234223, заметил ошибку, но она была в HTML, а не JS...

Comment: Всё работает...

Comment: да я там немного накосячил, спасибо)

Comment: @user234223, не за что